# Unable to downgrade python from 3.7 to 3.6 or 3.5

Tags: python, tensorflow, pycharm, anaconda, conda

Firstly, my anaconda got corrupted with error along the line of `activate.bat is not recognized as internal or external code`.

Then, I read about the error, and conclude that the easiest and most common way to solve is to reinstall. So, I reinstalled it 4 times. Everytime, it failed after I entered `conda install python=3.6` or `conda install python=3.5`

I also run it with administrator privileges. Also, I deleted all python and anaconda versions.

Additional information that may be helpful. Before anaconda corrupted for the first time, I was running running `conda install tensorflow` on `python 3.6` or `3.5` version. But while it was running in pycharm's terminal. I accidentally closed Pycharm. That's when I realised my anaconda had been corrupted.

Below is a screenshot of the error.
[image]

And this is what happen when I open anaconda prompt after the error appeared.
[image]
[image]

Any clues or helps to get me in the right direction would help. I really need to make it work. I have deadline coming up next week!!!!

Answer (score 0):

for now, I can use "conda create name_of_env python=3.6." to create virtual environment. But if anyone can provide me with a way to fix this problem. I still want to read about it.

Comment: Not an answer of your question. Please pass it to comment or better would be update the question.